# Find probability that X<Y

Tags: probability

If $X \sim \mathcal{U}(0;2)$ and $Y \sim \mathcal{U}(1;3)$ where X and Y are independent then what is $\mathsf P(X<Y)$?

I know that the joint probability distribution function is $f(x,y) = 1/4$.

According to me, $0<x<y$ and $1<y<3$ and hence I found the probability which came out to be 1.

But the answer is wrong! *Can someone tell me where am I wrong?*

Comment: Can you explain the problem clearly

Comment: You also require independence.

Comment: I don't think this is particularly unclear.

Here is what you did wrong:

$\int_1^3 \int_0^y \frac{1}{4} dx dy = 1$

You allow here for $X$ to exceed 2.

$\int_1^3 \int_0^{ y \wedge 2} \frac{1}{4} dx dy = \frac{7}{8}$

Here $x \wedge y = \min( x, y)$

Answer (score 2):

If $X,Y$ are independent, then:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X < Y) & = \mathsf P(X\leq 1,Y<2)+\mathsf P(1<X<Y<2)+\mathsf P(2\leq Y) \\[2ex] & = \ldots\end{align}$$

---

Think about what these areas represent on the rectangle $(0;2){\times}(1;3)$